# How do I make iTerm treat the Control key as both Control and Escape?

Tags: macos, keyboard, iterm2, iterm

I already have my Caps Lock key mapped to Control in Mac System Preferences/Settings > Keyboard. How can I also make the Control key work as the Escape key when it's pressed and released, without any other keys being pressed? I want it to remain Control when it's used as a modifier for any other keystroke. Is this possible in iTerm without the use of Karabiner Elements (or some other low-level system modifications)?

Comment: Either iTerm offers this function, or you'll need to use a utility or "low level system modification" to do this. What research have you done regarding remapping keys in MacOS? Is Karabiner the only option you were able to find?